# php floor precision incorrect

Tags: php

I want chop my float number, I found [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php#96568). First I want my value always division 10000, so my function will do it.

```
function floorDec($value = 0, $decimals = 2) {
        $c = pow(10, $decimals);

        $a1 = $value / 10000;

        printf("a1: %lf, type: %s\n", $a1, gettype($a1));

        $a2 = $a1 * $c;

        printf("a2: %lf, type: %s\n", $a2, gettype($a2));

        $a3 = floor($a2);

        printf("a3: %lf, type: %s\n", $a3, gettype($a3));

        $a4 = $a3 / $c;

        printf("a4: %lf, type: %s\n", $a4, gettype($a4));

        return $a4;
}

$a =  96684700;

var_dump(floorDec($a, 2));
```

Result

```
a1: 9668.470000, type: double
a2: 966847.000000, type: double
a3: 966846.000000, type: double
a4: 9668.460000, type: double
float(9668.46)
```

The variable `$a3` is not I want. I have no idea why. Thanks your help.

Comment: You are working with floats. Maybe `$a1 * $c` is not actually `966847.000000`, but `966846.999999999999999999999998`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is behaving correctly. This is just a side effect of the way floating point numbers behave.
They are sometimes just a little bit inaccurate:

```
printf("%.99f", $a2);
```

prints

> 966846.99999999988358467817306518554687500000000000000000000

so of course if you `floor()` that it'll be 966846.

Perhaps `(int)round($a2);` does what you want:

> 966847.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

---

If you need absolute precision up to a certain decimal point, have a look at these functions: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

Comment: Not just how they're *commonly* implemented, that implementation is what a floating point number *is*.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks, rephrased that.